# Why is this text not vertically centered in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have this HTML:

```
<div>1</div>
```

and this CSS:

```
div {
  background-color: white;
  display:inline-block;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  line-height: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 9px;
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

The text inside the div is not vertically centered in Chrome (it is 1 pixel above the right position). The problem is only noticeable when the text is small.

Comment: Browsers render fonts different ways, not much you can do about it.

Answer (score 4):

Visually, it may appear to be non-centered:

[image]

However, that is if you only consider ascenders. If you include a character with a descender, like g, it should make a lot more sense why Chrome positions it that way:

[image]

Comment: And this should be the standard behavior across browser, nothing specific to ``Chrome``.

Comment: Thanks for answering. If you check out this fiddle seems like the browser actually doesn't take this into account... http://jsfiddle.net/fyvyB/2/

Comment: @emanuele: I imagine the browser doesn’t measure it directly, but just takes some internal property of the font in use, where the font designer selects something that looks ‘approximately right’ in most cases.